# How do I prevent a route from changing before resolve has completed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I make angular wait until my service has finished loading before changing the route?  It was my understanding that using 'resolve' in $routeProvider would accomplish this, but it is not working for me.  I'm using Angular v1.2.1.

Here's how my router is setup:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute'
])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider 
       .when('/myRoute', {
            templateUrl: 'myTemplate.html',
            controller: 'MyCtrl',
            resolve: {
                MyVar: function(MyService) {
                    return MyService.query();
                }
            }
        })
 ...
```

And here is my service:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.factory('MyService', function MyService($resource) {
    return $resource("/api/example/:id",
        {
            id: "@id"
        },
        {
            query: {
                method: "GET"
            },
            get: {
                method: "GET"
            },
            update: {
                method: "PUT"
            }, 
            delete: {
                method: "DELETE"
            }
        });
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ngResource methods do not return a promise but a special resource object which doesn't wait for the request to complete. Thus, your route changes before the service has finished loading.
So, when using ngResource you need to manually create, resolve, and return a promise using $q service:

```js
...
resolve: {
  MyVar: function(MyService, $q) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    return MyService.query(function(results){
      deferred.resolve(results);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  }
}
```